# SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE `read_status` =0 AND `reciever` = 'admin-1' GROUP BY `message_thread_code`

Tags: mysql, database

Could you help me with this problem please?

```
SELECT * FROM `message` 
WHERE `read_status` =0 AND `reciever` = 'admin-1' GROUP BY `message_thread_code`
```

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column '3434_decu.message.message_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not contain any aggregated columns, so `GROUP BY` has no meaning -- the mysql parser doesn't know what do to with it. (The `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` error is not exactly the problem.)

So, for example, if you were trying to *count* the rows that satisfy your condition, you would use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM message 
WHERE read_status =0 AND reciever = 'admin-1' 
GROUP BY message_thread_code
```

If you simply want to return the filtered list, don't use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE read_status =0 AND reciever = 'admin-1'
```

If not, try editing your question to indicate what output you expected to receive.